# Docker errors with M1 processor and phpdockerio/php73-fpm

Tags: php, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile from macOS with M1 chip:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest

# Install nodeJS
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    supervisor \
    cron \
    git \
    ssh \
    nano \
    zip \
    php7.3-mysql \
    php7.3-mbstring \
    php7.3-gd \
    php7.3-soap \
    php7.3-dev \
    php7.3-pdo \
    curl \
    php-pear \
    nodejs \
    apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
RUN npm install -global yarn

# Install Composer
RUN cd /usr/src
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.10.16


# Install MSSQL extention
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qy apt-transport-https
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
#RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools g++ unixodbc-dev make
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install openssl mssql-tools g++ unixodbc-dev make
RUN apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssl \
    && sed -i 's,^\(MinProtocol[ ]*=\).*,\1'TLSv1.0',g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    && sed -i 's,^\(CipherString[ ]*=\).*,\1'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1',g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN pear config-set php_ini `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"` system
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN pecl install sqlsrv-5.9.0
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0

RUN printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo\n" > /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/30-pdo.ini
RUN printf "; priority=40\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/40-sqlsrv.ini
RUN printf "; priority=50\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/50-pdo_sqlsrv.ini

RUN printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo\n" > /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/30-pdo.ini
RUN printf "; priority=40\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/40-sqlsrv.ini
RUN printf "; priority=50\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/50-pdo_sqlsrv.ini

## Fixed locals for MSSQL extention
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen


# Setup supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
ADD .docker/php/crontab /etc/cron.d/laravel
ADD .docker/php/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
ADD .docker/php/php.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini

WORKDIR /var/www
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d` it gets to `RUN npm install -global yarn`, and it exits with an error:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = process "/bin/sh -c npm install -global yarn" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127I cannot seem to find a workaround. Anyone with a similar problem?
Thanks!

I tried commenting out RUN npm install -global yarn, but then it errors at either of the following lines:

```
RUN pear config-set php_ini `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"` system
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
RUN pecl install sqlsrv-5.9.0
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0
```

The error is the same:

```
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = process "/bin/sh -c npm install -global yarn" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

Comment: "but then it errors at..." with what error? The only actual error you've posted is when npm tries to run.

Comment: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = process "/bin/sh -c npm install -global yarn" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127